# Difference between "he said something" and "he mentioned something"

Tags: meaning, verbs, meaning-in-context

(a) What is the difference between *he said something* and *he mentioned something*? Can they be used interchangeably?

(b) Is it proper to respond to *Did I tell you X?* with *Yes, you mentioned it*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any place where you would use "mention" you could probably also use "said" (which is more general), but the reverse doesn't apply.  [Mention](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mention) is less substantial -- a passing reference, a brief comment, a name on a list, that sort of thing.

> My doctor said I need to lose 20 pounds and reduce my salt intake because of my blood pressure.  He also mentioned that I'm overdue for a tetanus shot.

This example is primarily about lifestyle changes and reports a passing reference to something else the speaker might want to attend to.

Per your second question, yes, saying "you mentioned it" is generally appropriate.

Comment: In OP's example, I think *mentioned* is probably far more appropriate than any construction using *said, told, etc.* It implies the first speaker may have only briefly touched on the subject, politely providing an excuse for why he can't remember whether he actually brought it up at all.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Ordinarily, choosing between these two phrases comes down to personal preference and context; their meanings are quite similar, with usages differing as suggested by Monica.

As a first example of context, in a long narrative *said* typically will appear far more [frequently](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=said%2Cmentioned&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than *mentioned*, as short, one-syllable words can be used repeatedly without calling attention to themselves, unlike obstropulous multisyllabics.  As a second example, in the context of [The Anglish Moot](http://anglish.wikia.com/wiki/Headside), *[said](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=say)* is *de rigueur*, being from Old English with Old Saxon roots, while *[mentioned](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=mention)* is from Old Latin via Old French.  Also see Wikipedia on Anglo-Saxon [linguistic purism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxon_linguistic_purism).

As an example of preference, in *[Politics and the English Language](http://www.mtholyoke.edu/acad/intrel/orwell46.htm)*, Orwell advises "(ii) Never use a long word where a short one will do", but tempers that advice with "(vi) Break any of these rules sooner than say anything outright barbarous."

(b) Yes